# Modify Z-index on Series object in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am using excel 2010.

I have a chart diagram on which i put a rectangle to surround the highest column bar.

In order to make things more readable, i would like to place this rectangle on the chart but NOT in front of the lines/bars/etc...It has to be behind them.

Shape objects (like my rectangle) have a ZIndex property than can be modified in order to achieve that. Thing is, it seems impossible to put that behind the elements of my chart, nor the chart itself.

The main reason is because Chart objects and Series objects (which are the columns inside my chart) doesn't have a Z-Index property.

Is there a way which could allow me to achieve this ? Other than modifying ZIndex property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the Chart in front of the Shape, or the Shape in front of the Chart. But what you are looking to do is to stuff the Shape behind some components of the chart, but still in front of the chart background.

That, as far as I know cannot be done.

But you can simulate the effect by making the Chart's background and the Plot area transparent (no fill, instead of the default White fill) by simply right clicking and adjusting properties.

Also, you can highlight both the chart and the shape (`Ctrl-Multiple Select`) and lock the two together so your Shape will look like it's a part of the chart and is behind the components.

Of course, the shape will be behind the whole chart itself (by setting the appropriate Z-value, which you may find by simply clicking on `Record Macro` and running the formatting once to get sample code) but since the chart's background is transparent and so is the plot area's it'll look as if the rectangle's behind the lines and all.